# RCDATA: Mixing strings and binary data

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

The next line added in a .rc will add the file NOTEPAD.EXE to resources as a binary data

```
0x3333 RCDATA "C:\\WINDOWS\\NOTEPAD.EXE"
```

however, using code below a string with value "C:\WINDOWS\NOTEPAD.EXE" will be added as resource

```
0x3333 RCDATA
BEGIN
  "Hello world"
  "C:\\WINDOWS\\NOTEPAD.EXE"
  0x9999  ;hex number stored as a word
END
```

How can I add a string and a binary data under the same resname (0x3333) ?

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381039%28VS.85%29.aspx) makes no reference to files as binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second syntax does not support external files like the first syntax does.  String literals are stored as-is, as you have noticed.